# Video codec for H264 with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, h.264, fourcc

I am trying to create a movie using opencv and I need that output file be in H264 format.

I used the following fourcc in opencv, but I am getting error that suitable codec is not installed.

```
fourcc=CV_FOURCC('H','2','6','4') ;
```

When I run my application I get the following error message:

```
Could not find encoder for codec id 28: Encoder not found
```

What do I need to be able to use this codec in OpenCV?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @sietschie: windows 7

Comment: You can also try CV_FOURCC('A', 'V', 'C', '1')

Answer (score 7):

H264 is not a codec, but rather a standard, while for example x264 is an encoder that implements the H264 standard (CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4') ;).

OpenCV can write videos using FFMPEG or VFW. You need to compile FFPMEG with x264-support (instructions can be found on FFMPEG's website)

If you are using VFW:  Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/

Comment: do you know the fourcc or id for the VFW x264 codec? If I use `fourcc=CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4') ;` I get a warning in the terminal and a vfw log window which I would like to omit. But the video is successfully recorded... so I just want to remove the warning messages and windows, I guess I would achieve this by providing the right id or fourcc code...